# How to assign colors to multicolor scatter plot with multicolor fitted lines in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, colors, legend

**Problem**

I have some data points stored in `data.frame` with three variables, `x`, `y`, and `gender`. My goal is to draw several generally fitted lines and also lines specifically fitted for male/female over the scatter plot, with points coloured by gender. It sounds easy but some issues just persist.

What I currently do is to use a new set of `x`'s and predict `y`'s for every model, combine the fitted lines together in a `data.frame`, and then convert wide to long, with their model name as the third var (from this post: [ggplot2: how to add the legend for a line added to a scatter plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593149/ggplot2-how-to-add-the-legend-for-a-line-added-to-a-scatter-plot) and this: [Add legend to ggplot2 line plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10349206/add-legend-to-ggplot2-line-plot) I learnt that mapping should be used instead of setting colours/legends separately). However, while I can get a multicolor line plot, the points come without specific colour for `gender` (already a `factor`) as I expected from the posts I referenced.

I also know it might be possible to use `aes=(y=predict(model))`, but I met other problems for this. I also tried to colour the points directly in `aes`, and assign colours separately for each line, but the legend cannot be generated unless I use `lty`, which makes legend in the *same colour*.

Would appreciate any idea, and also welcome to change the whole method.

**Code**

Note that two pairs of lines overlap. So it only appeared to be two lines. I guess adding some `jitter` in the data might make it look differently.

```r
slrmen<-lm(tc~x+I(x^2),data=data[data['gender']==0,])
slrwomen<-lm(tc~x+I(x^2),data=data[data['gender']==1,])
prdf <- data.frame(x = seq(from = range(data$x)[1], 
                  to = range(data$x)[2], length.out = 100),
                  gender = as.factor(rep(1,100)))
prdm <- data.frame(x = seq(from = range(data$x)[1], 
                  to = range(data$x)[2], length.out = 100),
                  gender = as.factor(rep(0,100)))
prdf$fit <- predict(fullmodel, newdata = prdf)
prdm$fit <- predict(fullmodel, newdata = prdm)
rawplotdata<-data.frame(x=prdf$x, fullf=prdf$fit, fullm=prdm$fit, 
                     linf=predict(slrwomen, newdata = prdf),
                     linm=predict(slrmen, newdata = prdm))
plotdata<-reshape2::melt(rawplotdata,id.vars="x",
                         measure.vars=c("fullf","fullm","linf","linm"),
                         variable.name="fitmethod", value.name="y")
plotdata$fitmethod<-as.factor(plotdata$fitmethod)

plt <- ggplot() + 
       geom_line(data = plotdata, aes(x = x, y = y, group = fitmethod, 
                                      colour=fitmethod)) +
       scale_colour_manual(name = "Fit Methods", 
                           values = c("fullf" = "lightskyblue", 
                                      "linf" = "cornflowerblue",
                                      "fullm"="darkseagreen", "linm" = "olivedrab")) +
       geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = gender)) +
       scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","green"))  ## This does not work as I expected...
show(plt)
```

[image: Points cannot be coloured]

Code for another method (omitted two lines), which generates same-colour legend and multi-color plot:

```r
ggplot(data = prdf, aes(x = x, y = fit)) +  # prdf and prdm are just data frames containing the x's and fitted values for different models
       geom_line(aes(lty="Female"),colour = "chocolate") +
       geom_line(data = prdm, aes(x = x, y = fit, lty="Male"), colour = "darkblue") + 
       geom_point(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = gender)) +
       scale_colour_discrete(name="Gender", breaks=c(0,1), 
                             labels=c("Male","Female"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is related to using the `colour` aesthetic for lines and the `fill` aesthetics for points in your own (first) example. In the second example, it works because the `colour` aesthetic is used for lines and points.

By default, **`geom_point` can not map a variable to `fill`**, because the default point shape (19) doesn't have a fill.

For `fill` to work on points, you have to specify `shape = 21:25` in `geom_point()`, outside of `aes()`.

Perhaps this small reproducible example helps to illustrate the point:

**Simulate data**

```r
set.seed(4821)
x1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)

set.seed(4821)
x2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 6)

data <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(20,80,length.out = 100),2),
                   tc = c(x1, x2),
                   gender = factor(c(rep("Female", 100), rep("Male", 100))))
```

**Fit models**

```r
slrmen <-lm(tc~x+I(x^2), data = data[data["gender"]=="Male",])
slrwomen <-lm(tc~x+I(x^2),data = data[data["gender"]=="Female",])

newdat <- data.frame(x = seq(20,80,length.out = 200))

fitted.male <- data.frame(x = newdat,
                          gender = "Male",
                          tc = predict(object = slrmen, newdata = newdat))
fitted.female <- data.frame(x = newdat,
                           gender = "Female",
                           tc = predict(object = slrwomen, newdata = newdat))
```

**Plot using `colour` aesthetics**

Use the `colour` aesthetics for both points and lines (specify in `ggplot` such that it gets inherited throughout). By default, `geom_point` can map a variable to `colour`.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = tc, colour = gender)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(data = fitted.male) +
  geom_line(data = fitted.female) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("tomato","blue")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**Plot using `colour` and `fill` aesthetics**

Use the `fill` aesthetics for points and the `colour` aesthetics for  lines (specify aesthetics in `geom_*` to prevent them being inherited). This will reproduce the problem.

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = tc)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = gender)) +
  geom_line(data = fitted.male, aes(colour = gender)) +
  geom_line(data = fitted.female, aes(colour = gender)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("tomato","blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("tomato","blue")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

To fix this, change the `shape` argument in `geom_point` to a point shape that can be filled (21:25).

```r
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = tc)) +
  geom_point(aes(fill = gender), shape = 21) +
  geom_line(data = fitted.male, aes(colour = gender)) +
  geom_line(data = fitted.female, aes(colour = gender)) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("tomato","blue")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("tomato","blue")) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Note that the scales for colour and fill get merged automatically if the same variable is mapped to both aesthetics.

Comment: Thanks you so much scrameri!  I didn't realize that geom_points are not "fillable".  I guess what I would use is the last method, changing the points to another shape, because I need to draw multiple lines and separately assign colours (say, 4 fitted lines and 2 different points), so the previous two methods might not be applicable.

Comment: Also do you know why in my second method, I cannot assign two colours to the two lines even if I have manually put in different colours to `colour` outside of `aes` but within `geom_line`?  (In fact, I am not really expecting a dashed line)

Comment: Hi Jasper :) I'm not sure what happens exactly with your linetype, but you probably shouldn't map a character such as "Male" or "Female" to the linetype aesthetic. Did you try specifying `geom_line(colour = "chocolate", linetype = 1)` and `geom_line(data = prdm, aes(x = x, y = fit), linetype = 2, colour = "darkblue")` instead?

Comment: Alternatively, you could `rbind` all your `data.frames` with x and fit values into `prdm`, and add additional variables `gender` and `model` specifying model type, and then use everything to map to the linetype and colour aesthetic in one go: `geom_line(data = prdm, aes(x = x, y = fit, linetype = type, colour = gender)`

Comment: Just used a character (not a variable name) in `aes` myself. Such an approach is similar to mapping a variable from your data.frame to an aesthetic: in your example, you first mapped `lty` to "Female", which produced the solid line, and then you mapped `lty` to "Male", which is then interpreted as a second level of some factor. But that factor isn't your `gender` variable in `prdf`and `prdm`. To map `gender` to `linetype` (lty), you can use `aes(linetype = gender)`. If you dont' want different linetypes, you shouldn't specify `linetype` inside `aes`. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much scrameri!  Your examples help a lot.  Yes, `lty` seems not meant to be used in this way...  The reason I used it was just I wanted to make legends directly for the data within `geom_line`.  Now I believe it shouldn't be used in this way.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that what you really want to do is use `ggplot2::stat_smooth` instead of trying to predict yourself.

Borrowing the data from @scrameri:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = tc, color = gender)) +
   geom_point() +
   stat_smooth(aes(linetype = "X^2"), method = 'lm',formula = y~x + I(x^2)) +
   stat_smooth(aes(linetype = "X^3"), method = 'lm',formula = y~x + I(x^2) + I(x^3)) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("darkseagreen","lightskyblue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ian!  I didn't know I can fit directly in `ggplot2` till now.  Interesting feature.  However, simple regression might only be a special case, and oftentimes I think more advanced fits need to be done outside of `ggplot()`, with only fitted points fed into it.  In this case I guess usually a more precise manual control would be desired.  Still thanks for your great answer!